# Convert instances of objects to be able to loop through

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object that has properties that include strings, int, and doubles.
I have three instances of the object : item1, item2, item 3.

I can print out the value by saying item1.name etc.
But how can I loop through the object and print the values?
I don't think I can convert the object to a list or array as the object has different types - right?

Comment: Can you clarify if all the objects are of the same type?

Comment: The object properties are different types - 
I have ObjectName.ID = int, ObjectName.Name = string etc.

Comment: Are item1, item2, and item3 of the same Type? If so, you can make a List of them.

Comment: Item1, Item2, Item3 are all instances of the same Object.

Comment: Saying they are all instances of the same object doesn't make sense.  They are all instances of the same class?  (by definition, an object is an instance of a class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean they are all instances of the same class, then it is pretty basic what you can do in this situation. If this is the case, you can create a List of that class type. Then iterate over the objects in any way you wish to, and you will be able to print out any of the public properties the class contains.

```
var examples = new List<ExampleObject>()
{
   new ExampleObject { ID = 1, Name = "Display" },
   new ExampleObject { ID = 2, Name = "Display2" },
};

examples.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("id = {0}, name =  {1}", x.ID, x.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all have a "name" property, you could create an interface including that property.

```
public Interface IShowName
{
    string Name { get; }

}
```

Then make each type implement IShowName (which according to you, they already do).  Then you could put them all into a list of IShowName.

```
var myList = new List<IShowName>();
myList.Add(obj1);
myList.Add(obj2);
myList.Add(obj3);

foreach(var nameShower in myList)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(nameShower.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think its what I need - The object has 7 properties and I have 3 instances of the property - So I need to loop through each instance and display the values of each of the 7 properties. _ does that make sense?

Comment: So, for a given object, you want to write out all of the properties?  And you don't know the type of the object?  It sounds like Reflection is in your future.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj1.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    //If property is public
    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
    {
        object propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj1, null);
        System.Console.WriteLine(propValue.ToString());
    }
}
```